# What am I doing wrong with this prototype setup?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

See the simplified code. What am I not getting with this pattern?

```
    var john = new person('john');
    john.hi();

    function person(name) {
      this.name = name;
    }

    person.prototype.hi = function() {
      console.log('hi there. Name is ' + this.name);
    };
```

Comment: Looks fine to me... Try instantiating after the declaration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there's anything wrong it is the order of things. Other than that this seems correct.

```
function person(name) {
  this.name = name;
}

person.prototype.hi = function() {
  console.log('hi there. Name is ' + this.name);
};

var john = new person('john');
john.hi();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also add prototype function after the creation of your object, and this function can be called by all the instances, even those created before. Because when you call a function, the prototype chain will be searched if no function is found on your object itself.